# Is it possible to access all gui components on a window using tag

Tags: cocoa

I hope to access all gui components on a window using tag.
But I found that some components are in the subview of the window, so

```
NSButton *aButton=(NSButton*)[self.window.contentView viewWithTag:tag];
```

will return 0x0, I have to change super view of the button from 'self.window.contentView' to the subview that includes the NSButton

Is there general way to access all gui objects on a window using tag, it will recognize and set the correct super view of each gui component when I use

```
NSObject *a=(NSObject*)[recognizedSuperView viewWithTag:tag];
```

to access them?

Comment: Why would you need that? You know what outlets are, don't you?

Comment: Personally, I can imagine situations where I might create an arbitrary number of custom views, and want to identify them by tag.  In fact, a common example would be creating a scrollable image browser - many UIImageViews with UILabels as titles, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewWithTag:` only returns direct subviews that have a tag set.  If you want to navigate the view hierarchy, then you should implement a recursive method to do so, but be aware that you could find the same tag value in many possible locations in the tree.